# Trim all database fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Do you know if there's a quick way in sql server (via transact-sql) that I could trim all the database string fields.

Comment: Did you mean to update the length of the column to the maximum length found in a value of that column? I mean like having a column Name in table Persons where Name is VARCHAR(200) and in all of the 10000 rows the longest Name is 23 to modify the column to VARCHAR(23)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No cursors.  Copy and paste the output.  Works also for SQL 2000, which doesn't have varchar(max).  This can be easily extended to add a GO line to the end of each UPDATE if desired.

```
SELECT  SQL
FROM    (       SELECT  t.TABLE_CATALOG
                 ,      t.TABLE_SCHEMA
                 ,      t.TABLE_NAME
                 ,      0               SORT
                 ,      'UPDATE  ' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME)       SQL
                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES       t
                 JOIN   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS      c
                  ON    t.TABLE_CATALOG = c.TABLE_CATALOG
                   AND  t.TABLE_SCHEMA  = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
                   AND  t.TABLE_NAME    = c.TABLE_NAME
                WHERE   t.TABLE_TYPE    = 'BASE TABLE'
                 AND    c.DATA_TYPE     IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar')
                GROUP BY        t.TABLE_CATALOG
                 ,              t.TABLE_SCHEMA
                 ,              t.TABLE_NAME
                UNION ALL
                SELECT  x.TABLE_CATALOG
                 ,      x.TABLE_SCHEMA
                 ,      x.TABLE_NAME
                 ,      CASE    WHEN    x.COLUMN_NAME_MIN       = y.COLUMN_NAME
                                THEN    1
                                ELSE    2
                        END                                                     SORT
                 ,      CASE    WHEN    x.COLUMN_NAME_MIN       = y.COLUMN_NAME
                                THEN    'SET     '
                                ELSE    ' ,      '
                        END + y.SQL                                             SQL
                FROM    (       SELECT  t.TABLE_CATALOG
                                 ,      t.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                 ,      t.TABLE_NAME
                                 ,      MIN(c.COLUMN_NAME)      COLUMN_NAME_MIN
                                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES       t
                                 JOIN   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS      c
                                  ON    t.TABLE_CATALOG = c.TABLE_CATALOG
                                   AND  t.TABLE_SCHEMA  = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                   AND  t.TABLE_NAME    = c.TABLE_NAME
                                WHERE   t.TABLE_TYPE    = 'BASE TABLE'
                                 AND    c.DATA_TYPE     IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar')
                                GROUP BY        t.TABLE_CATALOG
                                 ,              t.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                 ,              t.TABLE_NAME
                        )       x
                 JOIN   (       SELECT  t.TABLE_CATALOG
                                 ,      t.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                 ,      t.TABLE_NAME
                                 ,      c.COLUMN_NAME
                                 ,      QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + ' = LTRIM(RTRIM(' + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) + '))'  SQL
                                FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES       t
                                 JOIN   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS      c
                                  ON    t.TABLE_CATALOG = c.TABLE_CATALOG
                                   AND  t.TABLE_SCHEMA  = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
                                   AND  t.TABLE_NAME    = c.TABLE_NAME
                                WHERE   t.TABLE_TYPE    = 'BASE TABLE'
                                 AND    c.DATA_TYPE     IN ('char','nchar','varchar','nvarchar')
                        )       y
                  ON    x.TABLE_CATALOG = y.TABLE_CATALOG
                   AND  x.TABLE_SCHEMA  = y.TABLE_SCHEMA
                   AND  x.TABLE_NAME    = y.TABLE_NAME
        )       x
ORDER BY        x.TABLE_CATALOG
 ,              x.TABLE_SCHEMA
 ,              x.TABLE_NAME
 ,              x.SORT
 ,              x.SQL
```

Answer (score 14):

Your question is a bit vague but is this what you are after?

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn= LTRIM(RTRIM(mycolumn))
```

That will remove both leading and trailing spaces from all values in the 'mycolumn' column in the 'mytable' table.

Answer (score 3):

loop over information_schema.columns and RTRIM the varchar/nvarchar columns by creating the update statement dynamically

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure you are doing a trim on VARCHAR string fields, not CHAR fields :)

That wouldn't do much good.

Comment: Ok, LTRIM has some merit on a CHAR column. Just not RTRIM.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone knows how to do this without a cursor, please post it:

```
DECLARE @CRLF AS varchar(2)
SET @CRLF = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
DECLARE @TAB AS varchar(1)
SET @TAB = CHAR(9)

DECLARE @template AS varchar(max)
SET @template = 'UPDATE {@OBJECT_NAME}' + @CRLF + 'SET {@column_list}'

DECLARE c CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
    FOR SELECT  DISTINCT
                QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_CATALOG) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_SCHEMA)
                + '.' + QUOTENAME(T.TABLE_NAME) AS [OBJECT_NAME]
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
                ON T.TABLE_CATALOG = C.TABLE_CATALOG
                   AND T.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA
                   AND T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
                   AND T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                   AND C.DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar')
        ORDER BY 1

DECLARE @OBJECT_NAME AS sysname

OPEN c

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @OBJECT_NAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @column_list AS varchar(max)
        SELECT  @column_list = COALESCE(@column_list + @CRLF + @TAB + ',', '')
                + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ' = LTRIM(RTRIM('
                + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME) + '))'
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C
        WHERE   C.DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_CATALOG) + '.'
                + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(C.TABLE_NAME) = @OBJECT_NAME
        ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION

        PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(@template, '{@column_list}', @column_list),
                      '{@OBJECT_NAME}', @OBJECT_NAME)

        FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @OBJECT_NAME
    END

CLOSE c

DEALLOCATE c
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated the answer of dan to use all tables in the database. Just run the snippet and copy the result to execute.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] SET [' + Column_Name + '] = ' + 'LTRIM(RTRIM([' + Column_Name + ']))' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns c
WHERE Data_Type LIKE '%CHAR%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

Entaroadun code worked pretty well for me, I just had to do some small changes to my requierements, and also I had to reset @colum_list on each iteration.

```
...
  PRINT REPLACE(REPLACE(@template, '{@column_list}', @column_list),
                          '{@OBJECT_NAME}', @OBJECT_NAME)
    PRINT 'GO'
    SELECT  @column_list = null
            FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @OBJECT_NAME
...
```

Answer (score 0):

-- V Quick and Dirty !

-- If this is to generate code to run on a single table, run this code with text output ;

set   nocount on

declare @table nvarchar(100) 
select @table = 'YourTableHere'

SELECT 'UPDATE ' + @table + ' SET ' 
SELECT '[' + Column_Name + '] = ' + 'LTRIM(RTRIM([' + Column_Name + '])), ' 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns 
WHERE Table_Name = @table 
   AND Data_Type LIKE '%CHAR%'

-- Run as text output (Query/Results To... Results To Text
--    Copy and paste the text output (excluding the last comma) into a new query window,  and run it .

Answer (score 0):

OK, that was quick and dirty but i have been sufficiently motivated by a current project to do this 'properly' - and with no cursors either, but a little sql concatenation trick.
Does use dynamic sql though:

```
--exec    spGenerateTrimStatements 'StaticImportMaturities'
ALTER   PROCEDURE       spGenerateTrimStatements
    (
            @TableName NVARCHAR(100)
    )
AS
    DECLARE @Cr char(2),    
                    @OutputString nvarchar(max)

    SELECT  @Cr = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
    SET     NOCOUNT ON

    -- Create table to store commands
    CREATE  TABLE   #tOutput(OutputText nvarchar(500), RowID int identity(1,1))

    -- Build up commands
    INSERT  #tOutput(OutputText)
    SELECT  'UPDATE ' + @TableName + ' SET ' 

    INSERT  #tOutput(OutputText)
    SELECT  '[' + Column_Name + '] = ' + 'LTRIM(RTRIM([' + Column_Name + '])), ' 
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns 
    WHERE   Table_Name = @TableName 
       AND Data_Type LIKE '%CHAR%' 

    --      Trim last comma
    UPDATE  #tOutput
    SET             OutputText = LEFT(OutputText, LEN(OutputText)-1)
    WHERE   RowID = (SELECT Max(RowID) FROM #tOutput)

    -- use subselect to concatenate the command string
    SELECT  @OutputString = ISNULL(@OutputString, '') + ISNULL(OutputText, '')
    FROM (SELECT OutputText
          FROM    #tOutput) TextOutput

    -- run the command
    EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @OutputString
```