# Is there a way to TRIM all data in a SELECT * FROM statement?

Tags: sql, trim

I am trying to select and trim all the entries from a table using the following statement:

```
SELECT TRIM(*) FROM TABLE
```

But I get an error.  Is there a way to return all entries selected so they are trimmed for blank characters at the beginning and end of each string?

Comment: The answer is no. But why do you store leading/trailing blanks?

Comment: And adding another thought: SELECT * is bad. You can never trust in whether the colums will be the same over time so the format of your output will change and your application might get broken. Use explicit list of columns for SELECT instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507869/trim-all-database-fields check this link

Comment: @jarlh Using PTF  makes it possible.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to specify each string column by hand:

```
SELECT TRIM(col1),       --LTRIM(RTRIM(...)) If RDBMS is SQL Server
       TRIM(col2),
       TRIM(col3),
       TRIM(col4)
      -- ...
FROM table
```

There is another problem with your proposal. `*` is placeholder for each column in table so there will be problem with trimming `date/decimal/spatial data ...`.

## Addendum

Using `Oracle 18c Polymorphic Table Functions`(provided code is just PoC, there is a space for a lot of improvements):

```
CREATE TABLE tab(id INT, d DATE,
                 v1 VARCHAR2(100), v2 VARCHAR2(100), v3 VARCHAR2(100) );

INSERT INTO tab(id, d,v1, v2, v3) 
VALUES (1, SYSDATE, '  aaaa   ', '     b   ', '  c');
INSERT INTO tab(id, d,v1, v2, v3)
VALUES (2, SYSDATE+1, '   afasd', '    ', '  d');
COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM tab;
-- Output
.----.-----------.-----------.-----------.-----.
| ID |     D     |    V1     |    V2     | V3  |
:----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----:
|  1 | 02-MAR-18 |   aaaa    |      b    |   c |
:----+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----:
|  2 | 03-MAR-18 |     afasd |           |   d |
'----'-----------'-----------'-----------'-----'
```

And table function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ptf AS
  FUNCTION describe(tab IN OUT dbms_tf.table_t)RETURN dbms_tf.describe_t;      
  PROCEDURE FETCH_ROWS;
END ptf; 
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY  ptf AS
  FUNCTION describe(tab IN OUT dbms_tf.table_t) RETURN dbms_tf.describe_t AS
  new_cols DBMS_TF.COLUMNS_NEW_T;
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. tab.column.count LOOP
        IF tab.column(i).description.type IN ( dbms_tf.type_varchar2) THEN
           tab.column(i).pass_through:=FALSE;
           tab.column(i).for_read:= TRUE;
           NEW_COLS(i) :=
              DBMS_TF.COLUMN_METADATA_T(name=> tab.column(i).description.name,
                                       type => tab.column(i).description.type);
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN DBMS_TF.describe_t(new_columns=>new_cols, row_replication=>true);
    END;
  
  PROCEDURE FETCH_ROWS AS
    inp_rs DBMS_TF.row_set_t;
    out_rs DBMS_TF.row_set_t;
    rows   PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN 
    DBMS_TF.get_row_set(inp_rs, rows);
    FOR c IN 1 .. inp_rs.count() LOOP
      FOR r IN 1 .. rows LOOP
          out_rs(c).tab_varchar2(r) := TRIM(inp_rs(c).tab_varchar2(r));
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    DBMS_TF.put_row_set(out_rs, replication_factor => 1);
  END;
END ptf;
```

And final call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trim_col(tab TABLE)
RETURN TABLE pipelined row polymorphic USING ptf;

SELECT *
FROM trim_col(tab);    -- passing table as table function argument

.----.-----------.-------.-----.----.
| ID |     D     |  V1   | V2  | V3 |
:----+-----------+-------+-----+----:
|  1 | 02-MAR-18 | aaaa  | b   | c  |
:----+-----------+-------+-----+----:
|  2 | 03-MAR-18 | afasd |  -  | d  |
'----'-----------'-------'-----'----'
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0ab143c53cd35f74957a3e14e4cc7a08)**

Comment: Thanks for downvotes. I will wait for Dynamic-SQL solution that will work for each RDBMS, check metadata and do trimming for string columns.

Comment: One trick to do it faster in `SSMS` is to drag and drop from object explorer all columns to query window. Then move all string columns at the beginning, use block selection and write `TRIM(` for multiple columns at once. Then move to the end of line, block selection and close missing `)`. SQL Server has `LTRIM(RTRIM(` instead of `TRIM`.

Comment: It would need `LTRIM(RTRIM(...))` in T-SQL as that doesn't have `TRIM`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Please refresh page. Last sentence :) I guess comments are not refreshed like answers.

Comment: @lad2025 I see it now. Maybe it would be better being edited into your answer, as some future reader may neglect the comments.

Comment: Maybe consider updating the data as a once off so you aren't running functions over your data. Depending of course if your app needs leading or trailing spaces. If you do this as an ongoing solution, you may want to trim the data in your app on save and update.