# How to achieve TRIM on a SELECT * query

Tags: mysql

MySQL's TRIM function works great when specifying a particular column name, as in:

```
SELECT TRIM( BOTH "'" FROM channelurl ) FROM posts
```

I need to achieve the same result when doing a "SELECT *" query.

This does not work:

```
SELECT TRIM( BOTH "'" FROM * ) FROM posts
```

Is there a one-step process like this that achieves this outcome?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391793/is-there-a-way-to-trim-all-data-in-a-select-from-statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have have to specify the fields to trim,

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH "'" FROM field1) as field1, TRIM(BOTH "'" FROM field2) as field2 FROM posts
```

for example if you have an `auto_increment` field in the table it wont work in the trim function.

Comment: I know I can do it this way, which involves getting the names of the columns and then creating the query (a multi-step process). I'm looking to see if there is a one-step process.

Comment: to answer that question no, because the `trim` function with not work on non char fields, also it's poor practice to write queries that way.